# How to reinitialize Angular model with nested data?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I've start a little proof of concept this week with Angular Material, and in this POC, I have a table that displays nested data:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="2">Employee Name</th>
            <th>Ovr</th>
            <th>&nbsp;</th>
        <tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody ng-repeat="employee in evaluation.employees" >
        <tr ng-class-odd="'odd-row'">
            <td class="photo"><img src="{{employee.photo}}" /></td>
            <td class="name"><span class="firstname">{{employee.firstName}}</span><br/><span class="lastname">{{employee.lastName}}</span></td>                
            <td class="column-align-center"><span>{{employee.grade}}</span></td>
            <td class="column-align-center"><md-button ng-click="toggleAptitudes(employee.id)" class="md-raised md-primary custom-button">+</md-button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="skill in employee.skills" ng-show="employee.displayAptitudes">
            <td colspan="4" style="padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;">
                <md-slider-container>
                    <span>{{skill.name}}</span>
                    <md-slider class="md-primary" flex min="0" max="100" ng-model="skill.value" ng-change="calculateAptitudesGrade(employee.id)" aria-label="skill.name" id="red-slider">
                    </md-slider>
                    <md-input-container>
                        <input flex type="number" ng-model="skill.value" aria-label="skill.title" aria-controls="red-slider">
                    </md-input-container>
                </md-slider-container>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Snippet from the Controller:

```
var self = this;

// Mock data...
self.employees = [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'FirstName1', lastName: 'LastName1', photo: 'img/photo1.png', grade: 0, aptitudes: [...], displayAptitudes: false },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'FirstName2', lastName: 'LastName2', photo: 'img/photo2.png', grade: 0, aptitudes: [...], displayAptitudes: false }
];

$scope.calculateAptitudesGrade = function(employeeId) {
    // The overall calculation happen here where I collect all the skills values for the employee.
    ...
};
```

It's working fine for the first row I modify. I click the toggle button, it shows a list of skills with sliders, I move the slider and the overall calculation works very well.

THE PROBLEM: whenever I choose another employee, the sliders are set visually with the previous values. How to have the sliders set to 0 for each employee?

Comment: Are you trying to have 1 slider that just updates with the selected employee?

Comment: What does the `toggleAptitudes` function look like? I changed the `ng-click` and it seems to be working for me: http://codepen.io/jamesfeigel/pen/WojvdV

Comment: @LoganRx When I move the slider, the calculation works for the selected employee and I get a Grade displayed on the row. BUT, if I toggle another employee, all the sliders are set with the previous value visually only, the model is not affected.

Comment: @machinehead115 it suck right now, I did something quick to set true/false to the right employee:
$scope.toggleAptitudes = function(employeeId) {
        for (var i = 0; i < self.employees.length; i++) {
                if (self.employees[i].id == employeeId) {
                    self.employees[i].displayAptitudes = !self.employees[i].displayAptitudes;
                    break;
                }
            };
        };

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ok ok, I've found the problem!!

Like I says, it is a POC and I did this quick. The problem come from the «Aptitudes» array that I have defined... and reused for every employee defined in the array...

```
self.aptitudes= [
    { id: 1, title: 'Aptitude 1', value: 0 },
    { id: 2, title: 'Aptitude 2', value: 0 },
    { id: 3, title: 'Aptitude 3', value: 0 }   
];

// Mock data...
self.employees = [
    { id: 1, firstName: 'FirstName1', lastName: 'LastName1', photo: 'img/photo1.png', grade: 0, aptitudes: self.aptitudes, displayAptitudes: false },
    { id: 2, firstName: 'FirstName2', lastName: 'LastName2', photo: 'img/photo2.png', grade: 0, aptitudes: self.aptitudes, displayAptitudes: false }
];
```

Instead of declaring an array, I have create a function that return the array:

```
function getAptitudes() {
    return [
        { id: 1, title: 'Aptitude 1', value: 0 },
        { id: 2, title: 'Aptitude 2', value: 0 },
        { id: 3, title: 'Aptitude 3', value: 0 }   
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your `ng-click` on the button change it from `toggleAptitudes(employee.id)` to `employee.displayAptitudes = !employee.displayAptitudes`

Comment: Yeah you're right, it is better that way! But that doesn't solve the problem if I click on another row, all sliders are still set to the previous value... But I've just found the reason!!!